# Select component from react-select and typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-select

I'm trying to use the Select component from react-component with typescript but I got some overload errors. Below the snippet of my code:

```
type SelectedProps = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  placeholder: string;
  readOnly: boolean;
  options: {
    label: string;
    value: string
  }
}

export function SelectFormik({ label, options, ...rest }: SelectedProps): ReactElement<any> {
  const [field, meta, helpers] = useField(rest) // <-- Had set some type here I guess

  const handleChange = (selected: SelectedProps["options"], action) => {
    helpers.setValue(selected)
  }


  return (
    <Box mb="2">
      <FormControl>
        { label && <FormLabel htmlFor={rest.name}>{label}</FormLabel>}
        <Select
          {...rest}
          {...field}
          options={options}
          onChange={handleChange}
          styles={selectStyles}
          isClearable
          isSearchable
        />

        <FormErrorMessage isInvalid={!!meta.error}>{meta.error}</FormErrorMessage>
      </FormControl>
    </Box>
  )
}
```

and the error I got:

```
(alias) class Select<OptionType extends OptionTypeBase = { label: string; value: string; }, T extends SelectBase<OptionType> = SelectBase<OptionType>>
import Select
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Pick<Props<{ label: string; value: string; }>, ReactText> & import("/Users/marcos/Desktop/fitup-next/node_modules/@types/react-select/src/stateManager").Props<{ ...; }> & import("/Users/marcos/Desktop/fitup-next/node_modules/@types/react-select/src/Select").Props<...>, context?: any): StateManager<...>', gave the following error.
    Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'OptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }> | GroupedOptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }> | undefined'.
      Type '{ label: string; value: string; }' is not assignable to type 'GroupedOptionsType<{ label: string; value: string; }>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: Pick<Props<{ label: string; value: string; }>, ReactText> & import("/Users/marcos/Desktop/fitup-next/node_modules/@types/react-select/src/stateManager").Props<{ ...; }> & import("/Users/marcos/Desktop/fitup-next/node_modules/@types/react-select/src/Select").Props<...>, context?: any): StateManager<...>', gave the following error.
...
```

I  read the error but i couldn't understand, if you could help me I'll appreciate. Thanks fellows. Sorry, jr developer being jr developer, kkkk.

Answer (score 0):

Your interface `SelectedProps` defines `options` as a single option object, when you meant for it to be an array of option objects.  That's the source of the particular error that you've posted.

```
type SelectedProps = {
  name: string;
  label: string;
  placeholder: string;
  readOnly: boolean;
  options: {
    label: string;
    value: string;
  }[];
}
```

It also seems like the type of `value` that is passed into the `onChange` callback is `any`, so I'm not sure what that `value` actually is.  Maybe setting the generic on `useField` would help to refine that.